# how to make speech recognition chat bot using wit.ai?

Tags: python-2.7, wit.ai

I'm trying to build a chat bot using `wit.ai`, which will recognize the speech and convert into text in chat bot.
Is it possible with the GUI of `wit.ai` to make such kind of chat bot?

I actually converted the voice into text, but facing difficulty to integrate the voice input with chat bot. How to do this?

Comment: Hey, have you tried this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLdjaKkJK_8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Till now, I able to convert voice into text...but i'm not getting clue that how to integrate this part with chat bot application  in wit.ai GUI...... I also gone through above tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

since the new release of messenger, you can convert speech into text, so if you are developing for messenger or another app with a good voice-to-text, you can rely on the app instead of trying doing it by yourself. In the end you're gonna have just text inputs, but people would be able to convert it's speech into text.